# how can i record audio stream with swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

I'd like to know if there is any way to record audio stream with swift?
I'm using `AVPlayer` to play the audio stream, but I couldn't find any solution to record the audio stream.
I tried to use the buffer but without success.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you found any solution?